# Flux integral simple problem

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Evaluate the flux integral $\displaystyle \int \int_S {\bf F \cdot n} \  dS$ Where ${\bf F}(x,y,z) = zy {\bf j}$ is the portion of the paraboloid $z = 1 - x^2 -y^2$ above the xy-plane such that also $x \geq 0$.

We derived the formula: $\displaystyle \int \int_S {\bf F \cdot n} \  dS = \int \int_R (-F_1 f_x - F_2 f_y + F_3) \ dx \ dy$ Applying this I get $\displaystyle \int \int_S {\bf F \cdot n} \  dS = \int \int_R 2zy^2 \ dx \ dy = \int \int_R 2(1-r^2)(r^2\sin^2 \theta)r \ dr \ d\theta$,

however, I'm having troubles finding the limits of r and theta, in examples I see online, they just take $ 0 \leq r \leq 1$ and $0 \leq \theta \leq 2\pi$, but I don't understand why, also - why is the $x \geq 0 $ relevant here? I don't see how I could project it and get limits for the x,y plane in this question

any help please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you have to consider only the projection of your surface on $xy$ plane i.e.
$$z=0\implies 0=1-x^2-y^2,x\ge 0$$ which is a semicircle and so the limits are$$r:0\to 1,\theta:-\pi/2\to\pi/2$$

Comment: is there anyway you could derive the limits without knowing how the projection looks like?

Comment: No, this is the region you have to integrate over.

Comment: thank you - one last question, if we instead (for whatever reason), wanted to project the graph $f(x,y)$ in say, the x-z plane - how would the formula change for the flux integral?

Comment: you have to define the surface as $y=g(x,z)$ and to get $(F\cdot n)dS$ as you did  before. in this case the projection will be the region bounded by the parabola $z=1-x^2, x\ge0$

Comment: would the formula then involve $g_x $ and $g_z$ rather than $f_x$ and $f_y$? (partial derivative)

Comment: $\displaystyle \int \int_S {\bf F \cdot n} \  dS = \int \int_{R_{xz}} (-F_1 g_x - F_2 g_z + F_3) \ dx \ dz$